# How to properly handle objects in a multi-threaded / asychronous application?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I have an application that is using asynchronous sockets with the begin/end design pattern.

Whenever I receive a new connection I create an object and store it in a collection. This object also stores the socket connection within itself and will be passed along in the begin methods "object state".

Now that the server is running asynchronously, sending, receiving etc, there are multiple code paths executing at any given time for an object.

What I do not understand is:
If I call a function passing in my current object and in another thread, that object was just disposed, what happens to the other object that is currently inside executing code.

EDIT:

ex.)If you look at ReadDataCallback() where it is calling doSomthing(). If it is about to call doSomthing() with my "device" object, but the corresponding device had an exception in the SendCallback(). What state is the device object in that is just about to call doSomthing()?

Here is a code example.

```
void waitForData(MyDevice device)
{
    try
    {
        if (device.SocketState.IsSSL)
        {
            device.SocketState.sslStream.BeginRead(device.SocketState.DataBuffer, 0, device.SocketState.DataBuffer.Length, m_readDataCallback, device);
        }
        else
        {
            device.SocketState.DeviceSocket.BeginReceive(device.SocketState.DataBuffer, 0, device.SocketState.DataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, m_readDataCallback, device);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        DisconnectAndRemove(device);
    }
}

public void ReadDataCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    MyDevice device = (MyDevice)ar.AsyncState;
    try
    {
        Queue<kustompacket> qps = null;
        int iRx = 0;

        if (device.SocketState.IsSSL)
        {
            iRx = device.SocketState.sslStream.EndRead(ar);
            if (iRx == 0)
            {
                DisconnectAndRemove(device);
            }
            else if (iRx > 0)
            {
                device.CircularBuff.Add(iRx, device.SocketState.DataBuffer);
                qps = device.CircularBuff.ReadPackets();
                doSomthing(device);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (device.SocketState.DeviceSocket != null)
            {
                if (device.SocketState.DeviceSocket.Connected)
                {
                    // Read data from the client socket.
                    iRx = device.SocketState.DeviceSocket.EndReceive(ar);
                    if (iRx == 0)
                    {
                        DisconnectAndRemove(device);
                    }
                    else if (iRx > 0)
                    {
                        device.CircularBuff.Add(iRx, device.SocketState.DataBuffer);
                        qps = device.CircularBuff.ReadEncryptedPackets(device.SocketState.SessionID);
                        doSomthing(device);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (qps != null)
        {
            MyDelegate meh = new MyDelegate(HandleDataReceived);
            meh.BeginInvoke(device, qps, null, null);
        }

        if (iRx != 0)
        {
            waitForData(device);
        }
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException ode)
    {
        //Socket has been closed
        //DisconnectAndRemove(device);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        //if (se.ErrorCode == 10054) // Error code for Connection reset by peer
        //{
        DisconnectAndRemove(device);
        //}
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisconnectAndRemove(device);
    }
}


public void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    MyDevice device = (MyDevice)ar.AsyncState;
    try
    {
        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        if (device.SocketState.IsSSL)
        {
            device.SocketState.sslStream.EndWrite(ar);
        }
        else
        {
            int bytesSent = device.SocketState.DeviceSocket.EndSend(ar);
        }
        device.ResetAge();
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        DisconnectAndRemove(device);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    if (device.SocketState.IsSSL)
    {
        device.Write();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about posting a code example describing what you are talking about?

Comment: It would really be easier to answer if we were looking at code rather than a verbal explanation of what you have done.

Comment: I posted an example of my code. If you look at ReadDataCallback() where it is calling doSomthing(). If it is about to call doSomthing() with my "device" object, but the corresponding device had an exception in the SendCallback(). What state is the device object in that is just about to call doSomthing()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an object is disposed on one thread, it is disposed on all threads. If you do anything with it after the other thread disposes it, it should (but is not guaranteed to) throw an ObjectDisposedException.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception.aspx

If you are disposing an object on a thread while another thread may be expecting to work with it, you are doing something wrong. Consider controlling life time of the object on a single thread in a deterministic way.

Comment: If the object is passed as the "Object State" in the beginReceive call, it is also possible that it is currently being used in the sendCallback. I am not sure how I would control the life time as you suggest. Please see my code example.

Comment: @Mausimo for starters you could try `lock(device) {` before every time you start to do anything and check whether it has been disposed already.  If it's disposed, don't use it.  Of course, this won't help you with calls already pending when you decide to dispose the object.  You may simply want to mark it bad and dispose later in some cases.  Similarly you'd want to `lock(collection) {` before changing it.